# How to encrypt webm media (specially audio) file using clear key encryption and obtain the key and key id

Tags: encryption, media, crypt, webm, eme

hi I can't seem to be able to encrypt WEBM files and get back any valuable information like key value or key id so i can use them with EME API and create a dash media player so i can protect my media files,
i am currently using webm-encrypt which encrypt my webm file and generate a key file but i cant seem to know how to use can anyone help me please

link to repo https://github.com/austinleroy/webm-encrypt

and if anyone know any other way to encrypt webm files that will be great, other than webm_crypt as i cant seem to figure out how to install it and make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found how to do it using shaka packager:  https://github.com/google/shaka-packager,
 by using raw key encryption i was able to obtain both key value and key id